# How does the '&' symbol work in template parameter？

Tags: c++, templates

What's the difference between

```
template <class T,class ARG_T=T&>
```

and

```
template <class T,class ARG_T=T>
```

Comment: It's a reference.  Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: This has me stumped on the default argument treatment. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820195/template-default-argument-loses-its-reference-type

Answer (score 3):

It's a good way of eliminating taking unnecessary value copies in functions based on that template, but in an optional way The `&` denotes a *reference* type.

E.g. you could have the function

```
template <class T, class ARG_T = T&>
T add(std::type_identity_t<ARG_T> v1, std::type_identity_t<ARG_T> v2){
    return v1 + v2;
}
```

The use of `type_identity` prevents an unwanted deduction to the `T` type (see [Template default argument loses its reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820195/template-default-argument-loses-its-reference-type)).

This means that a value copy of `v1` and `v2` are not taken. Of course, it's not always more efficient to take references, so for some instantiations, you might want `ARG_T` to be the same as `T`.

Comment: but when I use your code as add<int>(a,b) , the translater(vs2019 community) just analyze this into "int add<int, int >(int v1, int v2)" rather than "int add<int, int >(int &v1, int &v2)"

Comment: @mioyuki2009: Actually I get the same as you if I don't include the `int&` explicitly. I don't know why. I've asked the question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820195/template-default-argument-loses-its-reference-type

Answer (score 0):

Template type arguments are (dependent) type names. The ampersand after a type name makes it an lvalue reference. If `T` is already reference, then reference collapsing rules apply.