# Template default argument loses its reference type

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, template-argument-deduction

Consider

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class ARG_T = T&>
T foo(ARG_T v){
    return std::is_reference<decltype(v)>::value;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    std::cout << foo<int>(a) << '\n';
    std::cout << foo<int, int&>(a) << '\n';
}
```

I'd expect the output to be 1 in both cases. But in the first case it's 0: consistent with the default being `class ARG_T = T` rather than `class ARG_T = T&`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, just to be clear (after the somewhat complicated answers): your question has nothing to do with the *default argument*, because it is not used in either of the example cases.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For `foo<int>(a)`, `ARG_T` is being deduced from `a`, and is not taken from the default template argument. Since it's a by value function parameter, and `a` is an expression of type `int`, it's deduced as `int`.

In general, default template arguments are not used when template argument deduction can discover what the argument is.

But we can force the use of the default argument by introducing a non-deduced context for the function parameter. For instance:

```
template <class T, class ARG_T = T&>
T foo(std::enable_if_t<true, ARG_T> v1){
    //...
}
```

Or the C++20 `type_identity` utility, such as the other answer demonstrates.

Comment: For those who still don't understand: `= T&` is completely ignored if `ARG_T` can be deduced.

Comment: Fine answer for the question, but why not just `template <typename T> T foo(T&);` if you want to deduce a reference

Comment: @sudo - That will make `T` deducible, something that it wasn't originally.

Comment: @StoryTeller if that's the goal, then I'd go for type_identity without the indirection of a second argument

Comment: @sudo - The second argument may have more uses. It serves as a convenient type alias for implementing the function.

Answer (score 29):

You need to stop [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) for `ARG_T` from the function argument `v`, (with the help of [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity), which could be used to exclude specific arguments from deduction); Otherwise, the default template argument won't be used. e.g.

```
template <class T, class ARG_T = T&>
T foo(std::type_identity_t<ARG_T> v){
    return std::is_reference<decltype(v)>::value;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dPyHO4uD5WfyJ9Sa)

BTW: If your compiler doesn't support `std::type_identity` (since C++20), you might make your own.

```
template<typename T> struct type_identity { typedef T type; };
template< class T >
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
```

Comment: This answer should make clear that this is a C++20 feature, that this is 2019, and that not one of the major extant compilers fully supports the features touted for  C++20.